# Dynamic choices field in Django Models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

My models.py:

```
SHOP1_CHOICES = (
    ('Food Court', 'Food Court'),
    ('KFC', 'KFC'),

)

SHOP2_CHOICES = (
    ('Sports Arena', 'Sports Arena'),
    ('Disco D', 'Disco D'),

)

SHOP3_CHOICES = (
    ('Bowling Arena', 'Bowling Arena'),
    ('Cinemax', 'Cinemax'),

)

class Feed(models.Model):
  gender = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, default='girl')
  name =models.CharField(max_length=25)
  shop=models.CharField(max_length=20)
  location=models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=SHOP1_CHOICES)
```

Here if `Feed.shop == 'shop1'` I want to load `SHOP1_CHOICES` on `Feed.location`. Currently irrespective of what shop, it just displays the `SHOP1_CHOICES` (no surprise).How can I implement it? I am stuck, please help.

Answer (score 27):

From the Django docs: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices

> Finally, note that choices can be any iterable object -- not necessarily a list or tuple. This lets you construct choices dynamically. But if you find yourself hacking choices to be dynamic, you're probably better off using a proper database table with a ForeignKey. choices is meant for static data that doesn't change much, if ever.

Answer (score 25):

## Django >= 5

[More options for declaring field choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/releases/5.0/#more-options-for-declaring-field-choices)

> Django 5.0 adds support for accepting a mapping or a callable instead of an iterable, and also no longer requires .choices to be used directly to expand enumeration types:

```py
def get_scores():
    return [(i, str(i)) for i in range(10)]


class Winner(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    medal = models.CharField(..., choices=Medal)  # Using `.choices` not required.
    sport = models.CharField(..., choices=SPORT_CHOICES)
    score = models.IntegerField(choices=get_scores)  # A callable is allowed.
```

## Previous versions

This is my approach:

I use lazy for lazy load:

```
from django.utils.functional import lazy
```

Here, a helper to chose options:

```
def help_SHOP_CHOICES():
    SHOP1_CHOICES = [
        ('Food Court', 'Food Court'),
        ('KFC', 'KFC'),
      ]
    SHOP3_CHOICES = [
        ('Bowling Arena', 'Bowling Arena'),
        ('Cinemax', 'Cinemax'),
      ]
    return random.choice( SHOP1_CHOICES + SHOP3_CHOICES )   # choose one
```

Finally the model with dynamic choices:

```
class Feed(models.Model):
  ...
  location=models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=SHOP1_CHOICES)

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
     super(Feed, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
     self._meta.get_field('location').choices = \
                        lazy(help_SHOP_CHOICES,list)()
```

Comment: Where does choice() come from?

Comment: Where does choice come from? choice( SHOP1_CHOICES, SHOP3_CHOICES )

Comment: ok, this is just a sample. Choice [comes from random](http://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice). You should implement your own logic for your project! Not tested but perhaps you can send `self` as `help_SHOP_CHOICES` parameter. @Harry, is this you are talking about?

Comment: There are syntax errors in your sample, also choice is made up so shouldn't be used.

Comment: @radtek, thanks a lot, I have saw your suggestion was rejected, It is a pity. Answer edited now with your note. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well no they fixed the syntax at least on the tuple, but yeah choice is undefined.

Comment: In Django 1.11, the get_field_by_name() is deprecated. To do this in Django 1.1, you replace it with: `self._meta.get_field('location').choices = lazy(help_SHOP_CHOICES, list)()` where help_SHOP_CHOICES would be a normal tuple iterable you make for a choice field

Comment: @XavierBrassoud, c'est bon. Please, remove comments to keep post clean. Best regards.

Comment: This works in 2021. It should have been the approved answer.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think you should do this on the model, form is a better place. Or you should rethink your models. For example:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    pass

class Shop(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)

class Feed(models.Model):
     shop = models.ForeignKey()
```