# Dynamic django choice field

Tags: python, django, api, django-models, backend

I have 4 models: `Products` (the list of products: freezers, microwaves, tvs and pcs), `ProductType` (entertainment and home appliances), `Credit` (a credit is registered on each purchase) and `PurchaseReason` (the reason why the customer has bought the product).

The `PurchaseReason` depend on the `productType`, so the `purchaseReason` has a foreignKey field `productType`.

In addition, each `credit` has a `product` as foreignKey and a `purchaseReason` as foreignKey.

Also, I have the `ProductReason` field as a choice field in the `credit` model, and I want the options to be set dynamically based on the `product` field of the credit model.

I'm creating an API so I think this cant be handle with modelForms, but i'm not sure. The hard work would be with the serializers (DRF) and with the django-admin (specially this one because in my product the django admin plays an important role)

What would be the best approach to manage my models in Django?

Here are my models. In credit I'm not sure how to implemente the purchase reason:

```
class Credit(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey('clients.Client', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, blank=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey('product',on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    reason_purchase = models.ChoiceField(????)
```

```
class PurchaseReason(models.Model):
    product_type = models.ForeignKey(product_type, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    reason = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, blank=True)
```

```
class ProductType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, blank=False)
```

```
class Product(models.Model):
    model = models.CharField(max_length=30, default=None, null=True)
    product_type = models.ForeignKey(product_type, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Please provide your code examples

Answer (score 0):

When we use the foreign key, we need to mention the model name of that particular model so that we can integrate that particular model in that model as a reference entity. Have a look at this example.

```
from django.db import models

class Reporter(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.headline

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['headline']
```

you've not mentioned the model name properly. it should be **Product** in place of **'product'** in the **Credit** class, **product** field.

use this reference https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

i think you should be able to use the Foreignkey field properly after this. Although, if you can't, you can share the actual objective. i will help you to write the correct model.
Best wishes :)

Comment: Thanks for taking some time to review my question, but, even if that you say is true, my problem is not related with the foreign key, but with the creation of a choice field dinamically.

Comment: you're most welcome for your kind reply. I think these two links below should solve your dynamic choice issue:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001986/dynamic-choices-field-in-django-models